# Is an Oracle 9i Client compatible with an Oracle 11g Server?

Tags: oracle, client, oracle9i

We currently have an Oracle 9i Client running on an HPUX Itanium platform and are looking at upgrading the Server from an Oracle 9i Windows 2000 Server to an Oracle 11g W2K3 Server.

Is an Oracle 9i Client compatible with an Oracle 11g Server?

Are there any problems with this configuration or is it recommended to upgrade the Oracle 9i Client to 11g as well?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to keep the 9i client?

Comment: This is a mission critical application and just trying to minimize the impact. We compile the application on the client side which is running on HPUX Itanium and during the compile the DB server is used to resolve references to the schema.

Answer (score 1):

It should, but the compatibility matrix that will tell you for sure is locked away inside Metalink.  If you have a support contract you can access it here:

[Interoperability Matrix - Metalink Note 207303.1](http://metalink.oracle.com/metalink/plsql/ml2_documents.showDocument?p_database_id=NOT&p_id=207303.1)

Answer (score 1):

I have some java applications that need to connect to two different databases. One is Oracle 9i Release 9.2.0.6.0 and the other Oracle 11.2g
Tried the jdbc driver for 11g
([ojdbc5.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)) but couldn connect to 9i.

The  jdbc driver for 9i did connect to both databases ([ojdbc14.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc9201-092698.html))

Answer (score 0):

In the referenced Metalink article, it says the following about such connections:

"For connections between 10.2 (or higher) and 9.2 the 9.2 end MUST be at 9.2.0.4 or higher. Connections between 10.2 (or higher) and 9.2.0.1, 9.2.0.2 or 9.2.0.3 are not supported."

Cheers,

Opus

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is Compatible, I have upgraded our Test Server to 11gr2 on 64 bit Win2008r2 and My client are still 9i and have no problems what so ever. I just tweaked the tnsnames.ora to proper host and thats it